# How to manually purge dhcpd.lease?

Tags: linux, dhcp-server

How do I manually purge **ALL** `dhcpd.lease` ?

Can I just `sudo echo /dev/null > /var/lab/dhcpd/dhcpd.lease` ?

It's a special use case of testing ground; we have an isolated LAN for developers to do test run. And after each testing session I'd need to reset *everything* to initial state, including DHCP lease records. The test session would take few days to just few hours, so I can't rely on `dhcpd` auto-purge.

The DHCP server is running on Rocky Linux 8 (X86-64).

[EDIT]

The command should be `cat /dev/null | sudo tee /var/lab/dhcpd/dhcpd.lease`. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I manually release a DHCP lease on the DHCP server itself?](https://serverfault.com/questions/739022/how-do-i-manually-release-a-dhcp-lease-on-the-dhcp-server-itself)

Comment: `echo /dev/null` will output the string `/dev/null` ... and `sudo command > file` won't do what you think, the output redirection is still as the current user ... perhaps you wanted `cat /dev/null | sudo tee /var/lab/dhcpd/dhcpd.lease` (after stopping the dhcp server of course)

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah I mean `cat /dev/null`. Sorry for typo. Thanks for the `sudo tee` trick.

Comment: @RomeoNinov It does, but in the hard way. I don't care about the lease record during test run at all and I don't want to *carefully* edit `dhcpd.lease` manually between each test run session. I just want to zap everything. Actually, I'm asking whether there is anything in the `dhcpd.lease` file that I shouldn't delete.